# Regular grammar and context grammar problems

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

1. If $G$ is not a regular grammar, then $L(G)$ is infinte.
2. If $L^*$ is context free then $L$ is definitely context free.
3. If $G$ is a context free grammar that is language is $L$ (meaning $L(G) = L$),

   then there exists a context free grammar $G^r$ such that $L(G^r) = L^r$

   - $L^r =\{w^r \mid w \in L\}$

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive. Thanks.

Comment: @BabakSorouh I went ahead and changed the title a bit as part of the task of cleaning up all of the spelling mistakes. user14988, please check to see that I didn't alter the meaning of your question with my grammar tweaks.

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes, and I’ve made the change.

Comment: What does "definitely context free" mean? Note that for any language $L$, $(\{0,1\} \cup L)^*  = \{0,1\}^*$ is context free.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a full answer, but it’s too long for a comment.

(1) is actually false as stated. The grammar $G$ with initial symbol $S$, terminal symbols $0$ and $1$, non-terminal symbols $S,A,B,C$, and the productions below is clearly not regular, but $L(G)=\{01\}$.

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to ABC\\
&A\to 0\\
&B\to 1\\
&C\to C\epsilon C\mid\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

What **is** true is that if $L$ is a finite language, then there is a regular grammar $G$ such that $L(G)=L$; this is probably what you were really meant to prove.